# Image cloze deletion for declension tables

Tags: russian, anki, declension

I'd like to learn the declension tables for Russian and I use Anki to learn vocabulary.

Does anyone have any advice for learning these tables, and do you think there is a better way to learn the tables rather than image cloze deletion?

Edit: My idea is to create image cloze deletion flashcards in Anki, but I'm curious if anyone has used this, or finds it useful, or has any other ideas :)

Considering the following chart:

[image: Noun Declension in Russian Table]
[Source: https://properrussian.tumblr.com/](https://properrussian.tumblr.com/post/164970688286/my-little-gift-for-you-noun-declension-table-as-a)

My idea is to create image cloze deletion cards in Anki based on charts like this.

Does anyone have any experience learning these tables, or ideas on this?

Comment: Hi Matt, could you please explain the relevance of images to flash cards for declensions? What sort of design have you used so far?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe sure, I've edited my question.

Comment: All I can tell you is that when I have tried to learn things as a table, I have just learned the table, and then when I need to apply it, I am still looking things up in the table - just a memorised version instead of a printed one. That's not very efficient. I would keep two things the same (say case and number) and use randomly shuffled flashcards to give me a word root, possibly indicating the gender. When I could do that without too much thought I would introduce different flashcards for singular and plural, and so on.